# Change of SourceName prevents the log entry from appearing in Event Viewer

Tags: c#, logging, registry, .net-7.0

I cloned a windows service from  [dotnet samples](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/workers/windows-service)
When I run it in VS 17.4.3 I get the desired event log warning
[image: Event Log Warning]

However as soon as I change the SourceName in appsettings.Development.json the log entry no longer gets created. Instead I get an Error showing in the log

> The description for Event ID 0 from source Application cannot be
> found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
> your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
> or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
> had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Unable to log .NET application events. The source was not found, but
> some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source,
> you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new
> source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security, State.
>
> The message resource is present but the message was not found in the
> message table

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the new SourceName working by running Visual Studio as Admin
After I had it working I was able to open Visual Studio normally.

Comment: I don't recall that I had to run as Admin initially with the original SourceName